# R: mutate() with apply after select() using chaining

Tags: r, apply, dplyr, chaining

```
require('dplyr')
set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(5),
                 v2=rnorm(5),
                 v3=rnorm(5))
```

If I which to count the number of values above, say, 0 and put this in an new column I would do:

```
mutate(df, n=apply(df,1,function(x)sum(x>0)))
```

This would give:

```
       v1         v2          v3 n
1 -0.08458607 -0.1078814 -0.75979380 0
2  0.84040013 -0.1702891  0.29204986 2
3 -0.46348277 -1.0883317  0.42139859 1
4 -0.55083500 -3.0110517 -1.29448908 0
5  0.73604043 -0.5931743  0.06928509 2
```

Now I want to use `dplyr`with chaining and make the same thing on a subset of columns,`v1`  and `v2`, but cannot figure out how to give apply the right data. If I just do (after making `df` again of cause):

```
df %>%
   select(v1, v2) %>%
   mutate(n=apply(df,1,function(x)sum(x>0)))
```

...Gives the same as above (same `n`i.e. it counts across all three columns), while passing data with `.`or just blank: Does not work.

```
df %>%
   select(v1, v2) %>%
   mutate(n=apply(.,1,function(x)sum(x>0)))
```

or:

```
df %>%
   select(v1, v2) %>%
   mutate(n=apply(1,function(x)sum(x>0)))
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After we use `select` for subsetting the columns that are needed, apply the `rowwise()` function and then use `do`.  Here `.` refers to the dataframe that we got after the `select` step.  When we do `sum(.>0)`, it will apply that function on each row of the new dataset.  Lastly, we `data.frame(., n=..)`, gets all the previous columns along with the newly created `n`.

```
df %>% 
   select(v1, v2) %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   do(data.frame(., n=sum(.>0)))
#           v1         v2 n
#1 -0.08458607 -0.1078814 0
#2  0.84040013 -0.1702891 1
#3 -0.46348277 -1.0883317 0
#4 -0.55083500 -3.0110517 0
#5  0.73604043 -0.5931743 1
```

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly. Why didnt mine not work (the first try)?

Comment: @akrun can you tell us what did you do, in simple english sentences?

Comment: @user3375672 Your code  was calculating for each row of the full `df` instead of the `select` columns.  `apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x >0))`

Comment: @akrun, yeah I think I at least figured that out, but how come apply(1, function(x) sum(x >0)) didnt work - should the chaining not pass what left after the select() ?

Comment: @user3375672 The `apply(1, ...)` has only margin and function, but no data arguments.

Comment: @akrun but then at least `apply(.,1,...)`; shouldn't `.` carry the data ? ?

Comment: Can you do something to avoid loosing the rownames (if you have that attribute in your df?, like using dimnames() in some way...

Comment: @user3375672  As I mentioned, one option is to use `do`.  Besides, I don't see any benefit in using `apply` along with `dplyr`, which you can simply do it anyway.  Regarding the rownames, you can add that as a column if you need it later.